# what is wrong with this program (output) (if elif) (isdigit)

Tags: python

```
sheep = input("Please enter the number of sheep ")
if sheep.isdigit == False:
    print("Wrong input. Number should be an integer greater than 0")

if sheep >= 0 and sheep <= 39:
    zakat = 0
elif sheep >= 40 and sheep <= 120:
    zakat = 1
elif sheep >= 121 and sheep <= 200:
    zakat = 2
elif sheep >= 201 and sheep <= 399:
    zakat = 3
else:
    zakat = sheep // 100

print("The zakat amount =", zakat, "sheep")
```

Comment: Use `sheep=int(input("Please enter the number of sheep "))`

Answer (score 0):

Your output is inside of your else block. Remove it from there and the code should work.

```
while True:
    try:
        sheep = int(input("How many sheep?"))
        break
    except:
        print("Please enter a digit")

if sheep>=0 and sheep<=39:
    zakat=0
elif sheep >=40 and sheep<=120:
    zakat=1
elif sheep>=121 and sheep<=200:
    zakat=2
elif sheep>=201 and sheep<=399:
    zakat=3
zakat = sheep// 100
print("The zakat amount of sheep:" + zakat)
```

Comment: Also the `sheep//100` is for sheep >=400.

Answer (score 0):

`sheep.isdigit` returns: `<function str.isdigit()>`

Basically, `isdigit` is a function, so do `sheep.isdigit()`

So the code could be like:

```
sheep = input("Please enter the number of sheep ")

if not sheep.isdigit():
    print("Provide a number")
else:
    if sheep>=0 and sheep<=39:
        zakat=0
    elif sheep >=40 and sheep<=120:
        zakat=1
    elif sheep>=121 and sheep<=200:
        zakat=2
    elif sheep>=201 and sheep<=399:
        zakat=3
    elif:
        zakat=sheep//100
    print("The zakat amount =",zakat,"sheep")
```

Answer (score 0):

The input() will return string so you should convert it to integer.

```
sheep=int(input("Please enter the number of sheep "))

if sheep>=0 and sheep<=39:
    zakat=0
elif sheep >=40 and sheep<=120:
    zakat=1
elif sheep>=121 and sheep<=200:
    zakat=2
elif sheep>=201 and sheep<=399:
    zakat=3
else:
    zakat=sheep//100

print("The zakat amount =",zakat,"sheep")
```

Comment: The problem here is what if someone does `five`. That you will get a ValueError. So there needs to be a try/except

Comment: @astrochun view my answer

Comment: I see.... thanks so this code tries to check digit first actually

Comment: If I try to run it, I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'five'`. The problem here is that there's no meaning to a general user. The original has a print statement of "Wrong input..". Granted it seems like they want to do both isdigit and a non-zero number